# How to use JSX in data, computed, methods in VueJS SFC

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, jsx

I'm setting up an app for study. From React, I've known how to use JSX and when I'm writting in VueJS, I don't know how to use it here.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{this.message}}</h1> <!--Work-->
        <h1>{{this.messageJSX}}</h1> <!--Not working-->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "test",
        data() {
            return {
                message: "Hello, JSX!", // Work
                messageJSX: <span>Hello, JSX!</span>, // Not Working
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now I got this error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Vue'
    |     property '$options' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'router' -> object with constructor 'VueRouter'
    --- property 'app' closes the circle"
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html?redirect=true#createElement-Arguments) are quite good for such use-cases.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/jsx-vue2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it without using JSX. Thank you all (:

Do you know the name of using an object like a component below?

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{message}}</h1> <!--Work-->
        <h1>{{messageJSX}}</h1> <!--Not working-->
        <component :is="messageComponent"></component> <!--Work-->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "test",
        data() {
            return {
                message: "Hello, JSX!", // Work
                messageJSX: <span>Hello, JSX!</span>, // Not Working
                messageComponent: {
                    template: `<span>Work with all other components, not just span</span>`
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is a dynamic component: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components

Answer (score 1):

messageJSX should be string.

```
messageJSX: "<span>Hello, JSX!</span>"
```

In order to output real HTML, you will need to use the `v-html` directive:

```html
<h1 v-html="messageJSX"></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you but this isn't what I wanted. I want to use some other vue component like Foo then it will become ``messageJSX: <Foo>Hello, JSX!</Foo>``. Or some Component UI Library like ``<md-button>Hello, JSX!</md-button>``.

Comment: You can put make a file called Foo.vue and then you can import and use it anywhere. Read more about single file component https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template) plugin `v-runtime-template`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-runtime-template :template="template"></v-runtime-template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VRuntimeTemplate from "v-runtime-template";
import AppMessage from "./AppMessage";

export default {
  data: () => ({
    name: "Mellow",
    template: `
      <app-message>{{hello}} {{ name }}!</app-message>
    `
  }),
  components: {
    VRuntimeTemplate,
    AppMessage
  },
  computed: {
    hello () {
      return 'Hello'
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit, it is a nice example in the line of the OP goals, but still it needs quotes for the template, so not JSX-like.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done; a coworker did it one year ago, here is the diff of the commit

```
         marks[this.dots[this.dots.length-1]] = moment.unix(this.dots[this.dots.length-1]).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm") 
         marks[this.nowDate] = {
-              label: '',
+              label: <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>,
               style: {
                 backgroundColor: '#ffc107',
```

and it worked until I rebuild the webpack configuration. My guess is that some babel plugin can be used to claim that the content of a SFC is jsx and not js.

Answer (score -2):

JSX is only for React, no JSX in vue.js . they are different

maybe this is what you want:

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>{{message}}</h1> <!--Work-->
    <h1><span v-if="messageJSX">{{messageJSX}}</span></h1> <!--Not working-->
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "test",
    data() {
        return {
            message: "Hello, JSX!", // Work
            messageJSX: 'Hello, JSX!', // Not Working
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

No need to use `this` because the `data` is already bound with `this`

Comment: I wonder if this is JSX in VueJS. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX

Comment: sorry for my unreflecting answer. I never use JSX in vue. I read a little of your url, it says you need to install some extra plugins for `preset` and config in your `.babelrc` : https://github.com/vuejs/jsx/tree/dev/packages/babel-preset-jsx

Comment: Thank you, I want to return JSX instead of String because sometimes, the ``messageJSX`` is not <span>. It could be a Vue Component or a component from another UI Library.